# Cache anonymous HTTP requests (based on cookies)

Tags: python, http, caching, squid, mod-cache

I would like to add a HTTP (or WSGI) cache to my Python web application, for all requests which

- are either `GET` or `HEAD`
- do not have a cookie called `"session_id"` (known users get specialized, non-cacheable pages)
- do not have a cookie called `"_flash"` (this cookie is used to show the user some short messages like "article created successfully", even after a redirect)
- if there are cookies which start with `"__utm"` (created by Google Analytics) they should be ignored (not stored in the cache), but the site should still be cached

If additional common caching directives (like `cache-control: private`) or even ETAGS are taken into account it would be nice too, but that is currently not a requirement.

Preferable, I do not want to run any additional piece of software like Squid (but I will use it if there a good reasons to do so), so I will prefer a `mod_apache` based solution, or even some kind of `memcached` powered WSGI-Middleware; Other solutions are also welcome.

Many thanks,
Christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend checking out [varnish](http://varnish-cache.org/). It's going to be a lot faster than any WSGI-Middleware you write/find, and you should be able to do everything you want with it. Here's the tutorial for a taste of it's many features, options: http://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/tutorial/index.html

Comment: [varnish](http://varnish-cache.org/) seems to be great. I've installed it yesterday evening in front of Apache. It just took a couple of minutes (I've just copied the google Analytics snippet from the varnish site and fixed a bug in my WSGI toolkit which sent a `Set-Cookie` header on each request). Now everything works like expected. Many thanks for this great advice!

Comment: No problem, I've had great luck with varnish, it's incredibly fast and flexible!